# How to code in php to store a one to many relation in mysql database ? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have two tables. 1) School 2) Student
Each School shall have more than one student. One student can only belong to one school.

I am noob. I don't know the proper php/ajax code to store a new records in mysql database. I am using 2 select boxes. If I am going to choose school in 1st select box then 2nd select box only show the student who enrolled in designated school..

Answer (score 1):

The `Student` table has a column `school_id`.  That provides "many students -to- one school" relationship.